# Self-hosted WCF running in ANOTHER process - configurations issue

Tags: wcf, process, configuration

I am using the following structure - 
1. Process A - running a self-hosted WCF service
2. Process B - hosting process A

When simply running A - service works as expected (using app.config service's configurations).

When running B - service seem to not recognize A's service configuration. 
I added the entire  section from process A to process B.

How must I configure service's configurations in B's app.config?

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting from Service A?

Comment: No error, just can't get to the service. It seems as if it is not 'open'/ 'exposed' anywhere.

Comment: Have you opened the service yet?